# Application Explorer won't show in my Visual Studio 2019 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am following the Microsoft official documentation to build development environment for D365 F&O.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find Application Explorer anywhere in the Visual Studio IDE. (I am using the latest 2019 community version from Microsoft).

Is there any way to turn it on or maybe any more understandable guide I should try?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-tools/introduction-visual-studio

Comment: do you mean by `Solution Explorer` ?, if so, try check at `view`

Comment: as far as I know, solution explorer is unidentical to Application explorer